# Matlab insert values in a vector which indexes are contained in a structure without looping

Tags: matlab, indexing, structure

I am performing segment classification with Matlab. I get the classes in a vector and I would like to put these classes at the original indexes. Theses indexes are in a structure.

I would like to do this without looping.

The indexes are in a nested structure like

```
d.S(1) = 
   ids: [845x1 double]
```

The loop that does what I want is:

```
for i=1:1:N
   imC([d.S(i).ids]) = class(i)
end
```

Comment: Are you using the function `class()` or you meant something else? Also, what is the problem with the loop?

Comment: No, actually, I use CLASS in uppercase. This loop is really not efficient, I thought it woult be better with a arrayfun-like function.

Comment: I assume that `CLASS()` is a user-defined function. Please, assign the output of `tmp = CLASS(i)` one line before inside the loop and then `imC(d.S(i).ids) = tmp;` (note that `[]` are not necessary). The  run with the profiler and check what is taking up most of the time between the two lines and post the results here.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I did not answer your question. `CLASS` is a vector, one of the output of `[CLASS,ERR,POSTERIOR,LOGP,COEF] = classify(SAMPLE, TRAINING, GROUP', 'diaglinear');` which is run just before.
As I am not confident with the profiler, I used tic and tac.
`Elapsed time is 0.000000 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000009 seconds.`

Comment: You could vectorize the loop, but that would mean creating an additional vector which in total would be long as all the ids taken together. Before going that way, time the whole loop as is, then try to store all `ids` in a cell array such that you would loop `imC(ids{i}) = CLASS(i)`, and time it again.

Comment: Storing the ids in the cell array is slower. I think I will just keep the loop like this. Thank you very much for your help.